# No rule to make target f1.o, needed by f90_simple

Tags: linux, makefile, fortran

I have the following makefile. It works well for `.f` and `.c` files but when I have `.f90` file and want to compile it with ifort does not work?
Could you please advise me where I should change and how?
Thanks you

```
FCOMPFLAGS    =    -O -ffixed-line-length-132
CCOMPFLAGS    =    -O         

FFLAGS        =    $(FCOMPFLAGS) -fsecond-underscore
CFLAGS        =    $(CCOMPFLAGS)
LDFLAGS       =    $(FCOMPFLAGS)

LD            =    gfortran
FC            =    gfortran

MAKEFILE      =    Makefile
PROGRAM1      =    f1 

OBJS          =    f1.o      \
                   f2.o      \
                   f3.o                    

all:        $(PROGRAM1)    

$(PROGRAM1): $(OBJS) $(MAKEFILE)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROGRAM1)

clean:         @rm -f $(OBJS) core
```

when I execute "make" I get the following error,

```
make: *** No rule to make target `f1.o', needed by `f90_simple'.  Stop.
```

It seems that My makefile does not recognize *.f90 files, and my other question is do we have flag for ifrot compiler to be used in makefile
Thanks

Comment: Since you've provided no information on what changes you made to use `ifort` nor have you provided any indication of what the problem is (_does not work_ is not a useful problem description), there's nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: @  MadScientist Thank you for your respond, but when I have f1.f and f2.f and f3.f and use make it works. the same thing for files f1.f90 and f2.f90 and f3.f90 does not work, could you please tell me how I can fix it, or make my question more clear?

Comment: You should show an example of the command you entered, and show the output you got and explain why you think it's incorrect.  Please cut and paste rather than paraphrasing error messages.  "Does not work" could mean a million things: the compiler might not be found, your source code might not be found, there may be errors in your code, you may be in the wrong directory, you may need extra libraries installed, you could be out of disk space, your computer could be rebooting spontaneously... we have no idea and without even knowing what your problem is how can we help you solve it?

Comment: Also see [10.7 Old-Fashioned Suffix Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) in the GNU manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the implicit rule:

```
%.o : %.f90
<tab>$(FC) $(FCOMPLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: @ Jack one more question, why the line clean:         @rm -f $(OBJS) core does not work for me *.o  files will not be deleted? could you please explain this for me.

Comment: Put `clean:` on one line, and on the line below it, have `<tab>@rm -f $(OBJS) core`.

Comment: @ Jack and then each time I should type make clean?? is there any way to make it automatic?